# Preg_match is truncating last element from array

Tags: php, regex

I have a string sample

```
Kim Ward$541.30$0.00$611.67 Kim Ward$784.25$0.00$886.20 Kim Ward$1,807.45$0.00$2,042.42
```

I need to insert it into array. But it is always truncating the last element. I mean instead of 3 Kim Ward it is showing 2. 
I tried this

```
preg_match_all('/ ?([^\$]+)(\$[0-9\.]+)(\$[0-9\.]+)(\$[0-9\.]+)/i',$cus_block_string,$results);
```

Comment: Can you update the question so it will include the desired output - it's better than describing it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your pattern capture groups for the numbers after `$` to accept commas `,` as they can be present in numbers in the thousands `(\$[0-9\.,]+)`:

```
preg_match_all('/ ?([^\$]+)(\$[0-9\.,]+)(\$[0-9\.,]+)(\$[0-9\.,]+)/i', 
               $cus_block_string, $results);
```